# Get error on sudo apt-get update and on software updater

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Unfortunately, I encountered an error while running "sudo apt-get update". There are some links that cannot be accessed, and I am unsure how to restore the default repository. Here is the full terminal command:

```
Err:5 http://ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Failed to fetch http://ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ro.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Furthermore, I am experiencing an internet connection error with the software updater. For some reason, it is unable to detect that I am connected to the internet. I am using Ubuntu with the default settings and do not have any VPN or other software enabled. Attached below is a screenshot of the error:

[Error on software updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcggI.png)

These errors occurred after I updated the OS system with the latest information. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me resolve this issue.

Best

Comment: The link solved my problem, but I still have a warning that I do not know how to get rid of. The error message is as follows:

`Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'.`.

I would like to know how to remove this repository from the list. Can you please provide guidance on how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu   read the section titled "*Removing & Disabling Repositories*"

Comment: Thank you for your support, the link provided solved my problem.